# i'm working on aspnet with mvc with razor code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I don't get the meaning of following lines.

(a)
this is a line from .cshtml file.
I use kendo UI.

```
@Html.TextBox("textname", null, new { @class = "k-textbox", style = "width:97px;" })
```

(b).
this is from `app_data` folder.
i dont get the difference between HtmlEncode and HtmlAttributeEncode

```
public class AntiXssEncoder : HttpEncoder
{
    public AntiXssEncoder() 
    {
    }

    protected override void HtmlEncode(string value, TextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write(AntiXss.HtmlEncode(value));
    }

    protected override void HtmlAttributeEncode(string value, TextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write(AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(value));
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line

```
@Html.TextBox("textname", null, 
               new { @class = "k-textbox", style = "width:97px;" })
```

Will generate to the output something like

```
<input type="text" class="k-textbox" style="width:97px"/>
```

So, it is a helper that allows to generate a textbox with some advantages, such as binding, if they are part of a form. You can read more about it in MSD and [here](http://microsoftmentalist.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/asp-net-mvc-16-html-textbox-and-html-textboxfor-helper-methods/)

The difference between the other two methods is, as is described in [the MSDN resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdek0zbf.aspx)

> `HtmlAttributeEncode` method converts **only** quotation marks ("),
>   ampersands (&), and left angle brackets (<) to equivalent character
>   entities. It is considerably faster than the HtmlEncode method.

Comment: what is class="k-textbox" means?

Comment: `class` indicates that the browser must to apply the CSS class named `k-textbox` to the input. You probably must read about CSS stylesheets also